# Kubernetes upgrade of pod with PersistentVolumeClaim in ReadWriteOnce accessMode

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have postgres pod using a PersistentVolumeClaim for the database storage, in mode ReadWriteOnce.

To upgrade the pod using Helm is tricky because the new pod is blocked until the old pod releases the claim, and Helm won't remove the old pod until the new pod is ready.

How does one normally handle this problem? I can't seem to find documentation on this anywhere, and I would think that this is a common problem.

This is my pvc:

```
apiVersion: v1                                                                  
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim                                                     
metadata:                                                                       
    name: pgdata-claim                                                          
spec:                                                                           
    accessModes:                                                                
        - ReadWriteOnce                                                         
    storageClassName: standard                                                  
    resources:                                                                  
        requests:                                                               
            storage: 20Gi                                                       
    selector:                                                                   
        matchLabels:                                                            
            app: postgres
```

Comment: How do you manage your pod? Is it backed by a deployment/replicaset?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you are using **ReadWriteOnce mode**, my proposal is to use "**StatefulSet**" with "**volumeClaimTemplates**" it was tested successfully (however without helm).

As an example please take a look for this:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/

Please share with the results and your findings.

Comment: GCP is not up to that K8s version sadly.

Comment: It seems that my best solution is to avoid the requirement and simply use cloud sql.

Comment: Could you please provide more info: f.e. asked by @yanivoliver how it was deployed, and how many replicas you are using? Please share with your yaml files.